# Можно ли при тестировании с помощью python pytest selenium сделать ожидание полной загрузки страницы

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при тесте циклом, к примеру

```
def currency(self, browser):

        currency  = {
            "RUB": "₽",
            "USD": "$",
            "EUR": "€",
            "UAH": "₴",
            "BYR": "BYR",
            "BRL": "R$"
        }

        for i in range(6):
            search_currency = self.find_element(Locators.LOCATOR_CURRANCY)
            search_currency.click()
            search_dropdown = self.find_elements(Locators.LOCATOR_DROPDOWN)[i]
            search_dropdown_text = search_dropdown.text
            search_dropdown.click()
            # time.sleep (2)
            search_products = self.find_elements(Locators.LOCATOR_PRODUCTS)
            response = requests.head(browser.current_url)
            assert response.status_code == 200, f'The site returned the code - {response.status_code}'
            assert len(search_products) == 30, f'Amount of elements - {len(search_products)}'

            for search in search_products:
                assert (currency[search_dropdown_text.split()[0]] in search.text), f'Error in product - {search.text}'
```

Моя проблема в том, что элементы, которые нужно найти уже имеются на предыдущей странице и после клика браузер проверяет их, не дожидаясь получения новых элементов, поэтому ожидания мне не могут помочь.

При начале итерации происходит клик на фильтр валюты и моментальная проверка на соответствие знака валюты, из-за чего тест валится, пришлось добавлять time.sleep (2), чтобы избежать таких падений. Этот костыль мне очень не нравится, ибо при плохом интернете ожидание загрузки страницы может получиться больше и тест снова провалится.
Есть ли возможность сделать запуск проверки только после полной загрузки страницы?
Перерыл много инфы, но так и не нашел как это сделать, нашел set_page_load_timeout, но это не то, что мне нужно, мне нужно запустить тест после загрузки страницы, а не выставить максимальное время загрузки.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37787453/selenium-python-how-to-wait-for-a-page-to-load-after-a-click

Comment: "WebDriver выполнит следующую строку в сценарии только после полной загрузки страницы. В таких случаях нет необходимости указывать WebDriver отдельно ждать загрузки страницы." https://www.browserstack.com/guide/selenium-wait-for-page-to-load

Comment: Моя проблема в том, что элементы, которые нужно найти уже имеются на предыдущей странице и после клика браузер проверяет их, не дожидаясь получения новых элементов, поэтому ожидания мне не могут помочь 
@СергейКох

Comment: Если вы знаете какой должен появиться новый текст, то  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element и он будет ждать пока элемент не обновиться.

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что эти элементы уже есть на предыдущей странице @СергейКох

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам поможет следующий код, он внесет нужные настройки для браузера, если данный вариант вам поможет, буду благодарен, если вы поставите галочку на ответ

```
from selenium import webdriver from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities 

caps = DesiredCapabilities().CHROME 

caps["pageLoadStrategy"] = "normal" 


driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=caps, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe') 

driver.get("http://google.com")
```